# To become winter or to change it into winter

Tags: sentence-construction, vocabulary

A foreigner out of the blue asked you this:

> Question: Are you happy with the climate condition in your country?
>
> You: No, because it's sweltering. But when the north monsoon comes in, the blistering temperature mellows. I wish it would make the rainy season even colder, particularly **to become winter** so that it would be a freezing season then. I would be delighted.

Can you actually say **to become winter**? Or should I say **to change it into winter**?

Comment: In my opinion, your sentence doesn’t work. The rainy season doesn’t bring winter; winter arrives with the solstice. You could use something like _more wintery_ or _more winter-like_.

Comment: If I changed that into ...''particularly to be more winter-like'', will my sentence construction ok now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to use the word **wintery**. Do you wish for *a winter season* filled with snow, sleigh rides, and the holidays?  Or do you wish for *wintery weather* with snow and ice and cold winds?

When I think of winter as a season, I think of the winter months (Dec-Feb in the north).  When I think of snow and ice falling from the sky, I do associate it with the season winter but I would also describe that weather as **wintery**.

Comment: I get it, just the 'winter-like' word =hugging like extremely cold winds.